# Get databasevalue from Repeater asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a Repeater to get items from the database.

I place every item into the web user control page, with this code:

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "XXXX")%>
```

XXXX = attribute from the database, for example: Username.

In the .cs file of the web user control page, I want to get the ID(which is also in the database) from every single repeated element, any clue how I can do that?

For example:

The `<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Username")%>` is showing the username of every person who is in the database. And in the .cs-file I want to get the ID of that username. So I can use a SQL-query like this when a button is clicked next to that repeated username:

```
UPDATE Table SET Username = "Mike" WHERE ID = '" + #### + "'
```

I don't know what to write in place of the ####.

This: #### = ID from the repeated Username where the button is clicked.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a Repeater, a good way is to use a command button.

In you .aspx, define a command button in the repeater ItemTemplate:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repUsers" runat="server" OnItemCommand="repUsers_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="select" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id")%>' Text="Select" />
        <span><%#Eval("Username")%></span>
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In your .cs, capture the command button clicks:

```
protected void repUsers_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "select")
    {
        int userId = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        // do your db update here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your aspx page do the following:

```
<asp:Repeater OnItemCommand="ButtonCommandEvent" ID="myRepeater" runat="server">

<ItemTemplate>
...
<asp:HiddenField ID="recordId" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
...
</ItemTemplate>
```

Then in your code behind you can wire your button to do the following:

```
void ButtonCommandEvent(Object obj, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var temp = e.Item.FindControl("recordId") as HiddenField;
    //use the value in temp to insert into your database
    //UPDATE Table SET Username = "Mike" WHERE ID = temp
}
```

This will work as long as you have 1 button next to each repeated item.